# Writing to two specific positions in each line of a text file (or rather creating a new file with the information added)

Tags: python, file-io

aspiring Python newb (2 months) here. I am trying to create a program that inserts information to two specific places of each line of a .txt file, actually creating a new file in the process.

The information in the source file is something like this:

```
1,340.959,859.210,0.0010,VV53
18abc,34099.9590,85989.2100,0.0010,VV53
00y46646464,34.10,859487.2970,11.4210,RP27
```

Output would be:

```
1,7340.959,65859.210,0.0010,VV53
18abc,734099.9590,6585989.2100,0.0010,VV53
00y46646464,734.10,65859487.2970,11.4210,RP27
```

Each line different, hundreds of lines. The specific markers I'm looking for are the first and second occurence of a comma (,). The stuff needs to be added after the first and second comma. You'll know what I mean when you see the code.

I have gotten as far as this: the program finds the correct places and inserts what I need, but doesn't write more than 1 line to the new file. I tried debugging and seeing what's going on 'under the hood', all seemed good there.

Lots of scrapping code and chin-holding later I'm still stuck where I was a week ago.

**tl;dr** Code only outputs 1 line to new file, need hundreds.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
new = open('new.txt', 'w')

first = ['7']
second = ['65']
line = f.readline()
templist = list(line)
counter = 0

while line != '':
    for i, j in enumerate(templist):
        if j == ',':
            place = i + 1
            templist1 = templist[:place]
            templist2 = templist[place:]
            counter += 1    
            if counter == 1:
                for i, j in enumerate(templist2):
                    if j == ',':
                        place = i + 1
                        templist3 = templist2[:place]
                        templist4 = templist2[place:]
                        templist5 = templist1 + first + templist3 + second + templist4
                        templist6 = ''.join(templist5)
                        new.write(templist6)
                        counter += 1
                        break                     
                if counter == 2:
                    break
            break

    line = f.readline()
    templist = list(line)

f.close()
new.close()
```

Comment: Can you add your input and your expected output ?  I think it's more accurate than giving your entire code.

Comment: Are you just trying to implement a csv parser? just use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your samples and code correctly, this might be a valid approach:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infd, open('new.txt', 'w') as outfd:
    for line in infd:
        fields = line.split(',')
        fields[1] = '7' + fields[1]
        fields[2] = '65' + fields[2]
        outfd.write('{}\n'.format(','.join(fields)))
```

Comment: I think there is more work to do than adding '7' and '65'. There is some conditions to fulfill.

Comment: @nexus66 I'm not sure where you're seeing "conditions to fulfill", but that's the whole point of the "If I'm understanding ..." bit. The sample input and output appears to just be prepending '7' to the second field and '65' to the third field, and the code seems to be doing the same thing, although it has some issues with processing consecutive lines... Although  that's quite possibly because `new.write(...)` doesn't append a newline...

Comment: I've answered the question. Take a look and leave your feedbacks if you have any.

Comment: I think you're right. There isn't any confition. Sorry.

Comment: @twalberg I will have to try your method. Meanwhile I figured out what was wrong  - my counter = 0 should have been inside the while loop. the code works now.

Comment: @twalberg EDIT: tested and works, just had to remove \n from your code, didn't need blank lines in output :) Thanks a lot for a much cleaner and shorter script!